# JavaScript - Find and remove duplicates conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I am getting the coordinates (lat, long) from the device and storing pushing them in an array to be something like the following:

```
 [35.23223,-5.293222]
```

But, in several times those coordinates get duplicated (maybe the device sent the same coords, etc...)

For that, I've implemented the below:

```
 var uniqueCoords = [Array.from(new Set(coords))];
```

Which on each call, digs into the existing array and remove whatever duplicated coordinate.

However, that causes serious issues, especially when having (for example) a new latitude and an old longitude (i.e [35.23223,-5.319399]) or vice-versa.

On this particular example `uniqueCoords` will dig into the array find that `35.23223` is duplicated and remove and it will leave `-5.319399` alone, by the end of the journey It may end having :

```
[35.23223,-5.293222,-5.319399]
```

What I want here is to remove (lat/long) only when both, the pair **lat & long**, is exactly the same as a pair that existing already on the array.

Current code:

```
    this.storage.get('route').then((route) => {

    let uniqueCoords: any = [Array.from(new Set(route))];

      uniqueCoords.push(latLng.lat, latLng.lng);
      this.storage.set('routeTaken', uniqueCoords); 

  }).catch((error) => {
    this.presentAlert(error)
  })
```

Array of raw data:

```
   [35.7790733,-5.8453983,35.779335,-5.8465283,35.779705,-5.84782,35.7787533,-5.8482083,35.7780167,-5.8491983,35.77782,-5.8504883,35.7774783,-5.8518267,35.776955,-5.852945,35.7765,-5.8541383,35.7761667,-5.855425,-5.8566467,35.77628,-5.8579367,35.7763233,-5.8588633,35.776435,-5.8591367,35.7767667,-5.8594817,35.7776267,-5.8586933,35.7785467,-5.8577233,-5.8585467,35.77949,-5.8597567,35.7797183,-5.86081,35.7805917,-5.8606533,35.7817533,-5.8606867,35.7826217,-5.8618667,35.78295,-5.8636367,35.7834217,-5.8643667]
```

Comment: so everytime you are pushing 2  elements ? lat and long

Comment: Yes, exactly !!

Comment: Could you push arrays inside arrays, so you get `[[35.3, -5.2], [32.2,-5.9]]` etc. as keeping the pairs, would make it more readable than just an array filled with numbers

Comment: Is there a reason you're flattening the pairs instead of keeping them relational?

Comment: @adeneo I prefer to keep the array as that if possible, else let me know if there is a solution if I switched to `[[35.3, -5.2], [32.2,-5.9]]`

Comment: @Santi, there is no specific reason

Comment: why dont you push string of lat,long instead of two elements?

Comment: use this `var uniqueCoords = Array.from(new Set(coords));` instead of `var uniqueCoords = [Array.from(new Set(coords))];`.

Comment: the whole idea behind removing duplicated should be revised.. perhaps you should only skip those duplicates that happen in a row. the device may eventually get in the same spot next day and those should not be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very logical, step by step, no fancy shit way of doing it

```js
var coords = [
  35.7790733, -5.8453983,
  35.779335,  -5.8465283,
  35.7790733, -5.8453983,
  35.779705,  -5.84782
];
var temp = [];
var unique = [];
var uniqueCoords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i += 2) {
  temp.push(coords[i] + '---' + coords[i + 1]); // create some strings
}

for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
  if (unique.indexOf(temp[i]) === -1)           // remove duplicates
    unique.push(temp[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {       // split the strings back into array
  uniqueCoords = uniqueCoords.concat(unique[i].split('---')); 
}

console.log(uniqueCoords)
```

Comment: that is actually a very poor solution as its computational complexity is n2.

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski - and yet, I'll bet you good money it's waaay faster than the other answers

Comment: with just a couple of coords its all the same but add 10k of cords and then compare

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski - challenge accepted -> https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1779/0/unique-coordinates

Comment: change `coordinates = coordinates.concat(coords.slice())` to `coordinates.push(Math.round((Math.random()*360-180)*1e7)/1e7, Math.round((Math.random()*360-180)*1e7)/1e7)`

Comment: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1785/0/unique-coordinates and that is for only 1k coords. i didnt even attempted to go with 10k ^^ how much money did you bet? :P

Comment: adeneo check your foor loops performing now https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1785/0/unique-coordinates and that is for only 1k coords.

Comment: Good for you, you've just won 10 cents. It's in the mail. It's still more readable and faster for smaller arrays.

Comment: keep the good money :) for smaller arrays  speed difference of what 1ms? does not matter :P

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski - You did notice that the only real difference between the two examples, is the use of `indexOf` instead of using a Set to get unique values. I'll bet you good money I can make it faster by keeping my loops and using a Set instead.

Comment: Although, I would prefer a short answer, but it does the job. Thanks !

Comment: @HamzaL. - you're welcome. There are many ways to shorten it, but it was intended to be readable and easy to understand, as some of the other answers seemed a little daunting to grasp. I though at least one readable answer would be good, even if using a Set is slightly faster on arrays with 10 000 items, as you can see from the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

You could join the coordinates and split them after uniqueifying.

```js
var coordinates = [[35.23223, -5.293222], [35.23223, -5.319399], [35.23223, -5.319399]],
    unique = Array.from(new Set(coordinates.map(a => a.join('|'))), s => s.split('|').map(Number));
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you take the array of a point, like `[35.23223, -5.293222]`, you insert into the point an object. Another pont with the same coordinates generates a new object, which is not equal to the former array. For making both equal, you need some stringifing the array. This could be a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, or some more simple like joining with a separator.

---

The same with continuous coordinates in a single array.

```js
var coordinates = [35.23223, -5.293222, 35.23223, -5.319399, 35.23223, -5.319399],
    unique = Array.from(new Set(coordinates
        .reduce((r, a, i) => (i % 2 ? r[r.length - 1].push(a) : r.push([a]), r), [])
        .map(a => a.join('|'))), s => s.split('|').map(Number));
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not only is the answer great, but styling the SO console output is a nifty trick I've never seen before. Well done!

Comment: It's a pretty answer, but I would like to understand more what's going on, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, please note that my current array has the following format `[lat,long,lat,long]` and I don't have arrays inside arrays which you have used in your example

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski exactly!

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski Why are you so hung up on the input format? You've commented that multiple times but OP specified in the comments: *"else let me know if there is a solution if I switched to [[35.3, -5.2], [32.2,-5.9]]"* - As far as I'm concerned, anyone encouraging OP to switch their format to maintain a relationship between the Lat and Long is doing them a favor.

Comment: sry i guess i didnt earlier catch the part that you have quoted

Comment: @Nina Scholz great one; however I am getting on my code editor the following : `Property 'split' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: @HamzaL., please add the raw data to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz you mean the array content, or the current code?

Comment: what about the pattern `... 35.7761667,-5.855425,-5.8566467, ...` and `... 35.7785467,-5.8577233,-5.8585467, ...`?

Comment: @NinaScholz `35.7761667,-5.855425,-5.8566467` only exists once; however, the following shouldn't be `-5.855425,-5.8566467` as both of the a  longitude value, that's what I am trying to fix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153809/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-hamza-l).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `uniqueCoords` is formatted as `[lat,long,lat,long,...]` and `new Set` generates something similar to `[lat, long]`

```
let coordSet = Array.from(new Set(coords));

// search the uniqueCoords list
let exists   = uniqueCoords.find(function (itemCoord, idx, arr) {

    // only check on every other coord
    //   if the previous coord being looped over matches the first coord in the coord set
    //   if the current coord being looped over matches the second coord in the coord set
    //   return true indicating the coord-set exists
    if ((idx % 2) === 1) && (arr[idx -1] === coordSet[0]) && (itemCoord === coordSet[1])  {
        return true;
    }
});

// if a matching coord-set wasn't found, push the new set
if (!exists) {
    // called with apply so each item in coordSet
    // is appended to the uniqueCoords Array
    uniqueCoords.push.apply(uniqueCoords, coordSet);
}
```

Comment: Please specify why you downvote; if its a logical error please state why

Answer (score 0):

if you just switch to format of `['lat,lng', ...]` (as a string) your code will work fine.

But you should check for duplicates *after* adding new coords. Currently you do it *before*.

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.storage.get('route').then((route) => {

if (route.length < 2 || route[route.length - 2] != latLng.lat || route[route.length - 1] != latLng.lng) {
      uniqueCoords.push(latLng.lat, latLng.lng);
      this.storage.set('routeTaken', uniqueCoords); 
}

  }).catch((error) => {
    this.presentAlert(error)
  })
```